# Import Contacts from .vcf file in Android 2.1

Tags: android

I am able to retrieve all contacts from android in .vcf file using following code.

```
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
                        System.out.println("The value is " + cr.getType(uri));
                        AssetFileDescriptor fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                        FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
```

I don't know how to use this .vcf file to import all these contacts using code. The .vcf file contains all the details of all contacts including photos etc.

Cheers,
Prateek

Comment: hi prateek jain ...howz u? prateek i am also doing the same job as u done means i want to make .vcf file of all contacts in device in a single .vcf file ..but the problem is ,am able to  export only one contacts after traversing whole cursor..so how to make single .vcf file of all contacts? i can also share the code to u...pls help...and +1 also for helping question to me..  :)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I finally achieved the contacts import. The solution is to extract all the related files from Android source code and make few changes and it will work. :-)

Comment: willing to share which files and what changes?

Comment: Please refer my below response. You need to use all the files in pim --> vcard folder.

Answer (score 3):

As stated above, there is a built in VCFImportActivity baked in to the code of android itself.  I personally wanted to open an unrecognized vcf file from the gmail app via intents.  I would send an intent with the vcf data attached to my program which would then launch contacts app. 
If you save the above vcf file on to the root directory of the sd card ( or wherever the contacts app saves its exported vcfs), and then start an activity like so:

```
Uri stuff = getIntent().getData();
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, stuff);
i.setType("text/x-vcard");
startActivity(i);
```

Should start the contacts app on importing any vcf it sees at that directory.  So obviously, save that vcf file before you launch this code snippet, launch the contacts app (via a chooser that will come up maybe), et voila!  Android *SHOULD* start importing those contacts. [This is a solution off the top of my head]

If this doesn't, let me know and let me see what debug errors you get.

Comment: importing all of android source code is generally the wrong way to do things on android.  Intents are how you get things done by other apps in Android.  It is a functionality baked into android so that devs like us can "get at" things we would ordinarily not have access to. Either because the code is proprietary, or the functionality is privileged.  If you create an Intent, formed to the same type that an app you want to use can recognize, and you don't have a default app set for that intent already, then the app you wanted to use will be an option to pick it up when that intent is launched.

Answer (score -2):

I struggled a lot for importing contacts as a vCard in Android and after spending a lot of time I came to there are no public API's for importing contacts.

Only way in my knowledge is to reuse the source code of the Android. I achieved the same by reusing the Android 2.1 source code.

The files can be referred from

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/pim/vcard/exception/VCardException.java/

At right hand side explorer you will find all the files needed under the pim folder. The file which will be responsible to start the procedure is ImportVCardActivity.java

I hope it helps !!

Cheers, Prateek